# example of function in Lp for specific p values

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Please give an example of a function $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the following properties:

(a): $f \in L^p(0,\infty)$ for $2 \leq p \leq \infty$, but $f \notin L^p(0,\infty)$ if $1 \leq p < 2$

(b): $f \in L^p(0,\infty)$ for $2 < p < 4$, but not for $p$ outside this range

I'm pretty sure I figured out part (a) by letting
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} {\large \chi}_{[n,n+1)} (x)$$
but I'm not sure about part (b). I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your $f$ is in $L^p$ for all $p>1$.

Comment: Your example is not in $L^1$, but it is in $L^p,~p>1$. Its $L^p$-norm is $\zeta(p)$ with the Riemann-$\zeta$-function $\zeta$.

Answer (score 1):

Something like
$$
(a)\quad
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}\log(2+x)},
\qquad
(b)\quad
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1/4}(1+x^{1/4})}\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with your $f$. One typically uses that
\begin{align}
g(x)=\chi_{[1,\infty)}\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
is in $L^p$ for $p>1$ and that
\begin{align}
h(x)=\chi_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
is in $L^p$ for $p<1$.

For b), you could use a combination like $f=g^\frac{1}{2}+h^\frac{1}{4}$. Then,
\begin{align}
|f|^p=g^\frac{p}{2}+h^\frac{p}{4}
\end{align}
and one of the addends is not integrable for $p$ outside of $(2,4)$.